# Не собирается проект flutter на Android Studio 4.0

Tags: gradle, flutter

Не собирается проект flutter на Android Studio 4.0. Выскакивает ошибка:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not download kotlin-gradle-plugin.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50)

Comment: Не может скачать `kotlin-gradle-plugin.jar`. У вас `gradle` настроенный?

Comment: Что значит настроенный? До обновления проекты собирались и в online и offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

Выполните команду в терминале: `flutter clean`.
После чего выполните `Sync Gradle` в Android Studio.

Если не помогло, посмотрите в настройках Android Studio включен ли `Gradle` (возможно заглючил, выключите и включите его).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Dima добавил в ответ

Comment: У меня в меню Build,Execution,Deployment> отсутствует пункт Build Tools. Есть пункты Debuger и Deployment

Comment: Gradle в plugins  включен

Comment: @Dima значит копать нужно в эту сторону...